# Jupyter error - 'the kernel appears to have died, it will restart automatically' for a given piece of code

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, recommendation-engine, apriori

Whenever i run this code, it runs successfully, but the Kernel dies when the last 4 lines of code are executed, where the Apriori algorithm is used for Market Basket Analysis:
**Data set:**
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
import mlxtend as ml
print("test1")

retail_df=pd.read_excel("Online Retail.xlsx",sheet_name="Online Retail")
retail_df.head()

rslt_df = retail_df[retail_df['Quantity'] > 5]
rslt_df=rslt_df.iloc[:10000]

rslt_df.shape
rslt_df.head()

df = rslt_df.groupby(['Quantity','Description']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df.head()

basket = df.groupby(['Quantity', 'Description'])['count'].sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('Quantity')
basket

#The encoding function
def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1
basket_sets = basket.applymap(encode_units)
basket_sets

**#THE NOTEBOOK CRASHES FOR THE BELOW 4 LINES OF CODE**

frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift")
rules.sort_values('confidence', ascending = False, inplace = True)
rules.head(10)
```

Please help in resolving this.
I tried every method but didn't worked out for me.

Comment: `frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)` causes `MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (46185705, 3, 123) and data type int64`.  This command uses 8GB of memory.  My guess is, you're Notebook crashes from lack of memory before you get the error message.

Comment: As mentioned, this is due to a memory error. Seems that you have too many unique items. Running the notebook on Google Colabs with a high memory kernel (around 25GB RAM) should do the trick.

Comment: @skillsmuggler My system has 36GB of RAM, so using Google Colabs is not likely to resolve the issue..  `basket_sets` is `123 rows × 1619 columns`

Comment: Can you mention what you actually tried? How big is the array?

Comment: @skillsmuggler any code to read xlsx file in Google colab.I was trying to use it but i am getting few errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.

I changed min support to 0.5 or somethings else that are more than 0.01 and it worked!

I think it’s because there are a lot of output.
I hope this will help you as well.